# no desktop after upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to ubuntu 13.4

Tags: 13.04

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.4 at first I couldn't log in. I got the error "could not update ICE authority". Afther deleteing the file "ICE authority" I couldn't see anything on the screen. Also my "user" from the earlier install, is missing too, but I can see the files in the home/olduser directory. can any one help me out with this, I don't want to format as i have a lot of files and contacts and other data saved in the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading is a pathway that rarely runs smooth. It really is best to bite the bullet, back up /home then reformat & install afresh. By using an LTS you will hopefully have a stable five years of security updates, therefore wiping/installing less often. It all about the gameplan!

EDIT: Always clone your disk before commencing dist-upgrade, that way you have a fall back plan.

I hope you are able to recover a working install.

Comment: hi thanks for the tip, had to figure it out the hard way. wont happen again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you know how to enter the command prompt since you mentioned that you can see the old users files, correct?
Maby you can try this:
Try and reset Unity.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

If it does not work try and reinstall unity:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove unity
```

and then install it again:

```
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. i tried both but it did not help the first code gave some error so i decided to reinstall unity it didn't work either, any other suggestions? oh and apaat from getting my desktop working is there a way i could get back my old user (the applications) as i have got some important stuff in it lke contacts and notes.